# Cassandra collections consistency for simultaneous updates on different nodes

Tags: cassandra, distributed-system, consistency

How does cassandra handle parallel updates for collections data types?

What will happens when client tries to insert different elements into the same collection record on different nodes?

For example:

Node1 run

```
UPDATE mnemonic.users SET emails = emails + {'frodo1@mail.com'} WHERE user_id = 'frodo';
```

Node2 run

```
UPDATE mnemonic.users SET emails = emails + {'frodo2@mail.com'} WHERE user_id = 'frodo';
```

Do we have possibility to lost one of the elements?